# Using a django app as a central authentication system to other django apps

Tags: django, authentication, session

(I am relatively new to Django, so sorry if  I was misunderstanding anything ^^")

so let say I have app1 and app2, and I want to implement the same groups, roles and permission through these two apps by only having one database.

my idea was to create a central back end server that the two app authenticate through and grabs the roles from it. essentially this can be used for SSO(Single sign on) later. but now the target is to authenticate the user logging through one app and get his roles and groups from there.

In Django documentation I found "[Authentication using REMOTE_USER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/auth-remote-user/#authentication-using-remote-user)":
which should allow me to do remote authentication (which is my target), was able to make it run but how am I supposed to give it the link of the Django authentication server.

my understanding is that after setting this remote user authentication, all groups, roles and permission checks doesn't need to be changed since Django should have access to the remote server that it authenticates through.

I hope that I wasn't misunderstanding "[Authentication using REMOTE_USER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/auth-remote-user/#authentication-using-remote-user)" concept.
also if there is any other ideas on how to implement this, please let me know.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like REMOTE_USER is NOT what you're expecting it to be: when Django is configured to use this functionality, it foregoes Django's typical security, because it expects a web server situated in front of Django (e.g. APACHE or NGINX) to do user authorization on its behalf. In a nutshell, the web server passes along the user's id in every request it sends to Django in the REMOTE_USER header.

You expectations, on the other hand, seem directed at configuring a common Django app to authorize and authenticate users for other apps. This is a common configuration, and is effected by several steps, including these three:

(1) Adding to the common app's settings.py the other apps in the INSTALLED_APPS list. For example:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
...
'app1',
'app2',
]
```

(2) Include the apps URLconf in common api urls.py, for example:

```
path('app1/', include('app1.urls')), 
path('polls/', include('app2.urls')),
```

(3) Run `python manage.py migrate` in order to create the database tables for two apps.

You'll probably have to fuss with your urls in the common app more that what I've sketched out above; and you might add a middleware to prevent unauthorized requests any access until authenticated.

Comment: ah, so Remote user isn't it. Thank you. 
I don't want to merge my apps in one project.

I want to simulate a fully different projects getting integrated together yet they are both using Django

currently I created a different project with restframework and had the authentication back end in my app linking to it through APIs. yet I am facing some troubles on how to share user data and keep it in sync with little performance hit.